# Play framework render HTML & values on same page via ajax

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using ajax within the play (scala) framework to run some code after a click event occurs on a page. I want to return the results of that code execution on the same page.

EDIT: the goal of this is to display some rows from the database, along with form elements to fill out to update cells of the databse, all without reloading/or going to a new page

Is there a way to pass html + (scala) values into

```
Ok(...).as(HTML)
```

to display without directing to new a page?

I know Ok can take things like:

```
Ok(<h1>it works</h1>).as(HTML)
```

but I can't figure out how to combine that with scala values as well. Is there a smarter way to do this?

EDIT: the ajax looks like this:

```
var ajaxCall = function() {
var ajaxCallBack = {
    success : onSuccess,
    error : onError
}

jsRoutes.controllers.Application.scrape().ajax(ajaxCallBack);
};

var  onSuccess = function(data) {
$("#results").append(data);
}

var onError = function(error) {
alert(error);
}
```

Comment: One suggestion has been to use JSON, though I'm not quite sure how to then also display <form> elements for example. The suggestion was: Ok(Json.obj("page" -> view.page("bla").body))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you can. You can use [TWIRL](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates) templates:

Create a template "views/Application/contacts.scala.html

```
@(users: List[User])

<h1>Users</h1>

<ul>
@for(user <- users) {
  <li>@user.name</li>
}
</ul>
```

in the controller:

```
Ok(views.html.Application.contacts(users))
```